# pass dynamic values when export to docx using PHPWord in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, phpword, export-to-word, phpdocx

I am trying to export user details to **.docx** file. The file successfully exported but, it's giving the object. Phpword format is not working. How to write code to export the dynamic values properly, would someone help me, please?

In **AdminController.php** -

```
public function exportUserToDoc(Request $request, $id)
{
    $wordTest = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\PhpWord();
    $newSection = $wordTest->addSection();

    $desc1 = User::find($id);

    $newSection->addText($desc1, array('name' => $desc1->name, 'email' => $desc1->email, 'phone' => $desc1->phone, 'address' => $desc1->address));
    $objectWriter = \PhpOffice\PhpWord\IOFactory::createWriter($wordTest, 'Word2007');
    try{
        $objectWriter->save(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
    }catch (Exception $e){

    }
    return response()->download(storage_path('TestWordFile.docx'));
}
```

After downloading the doc file the result is like -

```
{"id":1,"name":"Emdadul Huq Shikder","email":"emdadulshikder@gmail.com","phone":"+8801674338411","address":"59\/6\/1 West Razabazar, Dhaka","status":0,"created_at":"2018-03-13 05:18:32","updated_at":"2018-03-13 05:35:51"}
```

I want to get the result as well formatted such as with header 'Name', 'Email' etc.

Comment: in phpword version 0.13.0: `addText(string $text, mixed $fStyle = null, mixed $pStyle = null)` 

i.e. you need to pass your formatted text *string* to the addText function as the first parameter.

Comment: what do you want to achieve? How should it be formatted? One solution is the one proposed by eMM (use the TemplateProcessor), the other solution is to add the text as you are doing, but you should format the text before adding it. Check out the samples/Sample_04_Textrun.php file for examples

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**Step 1:**
Create a `.docx` file using a word processing program(OpenOffice, LibreOffice Writer, MS Word etc.) which will serve as the template of your 'User Document'(this way you can set size, margins, orientation and other attributes and also format your document creatively using the tools provided in the word processing program you use).

For dynamic values in your document, you can use variables as placeholders. The syntax of a document variable is `${variable}`. Make sure that your variable names are unique.

Here's a screenshot of an example document template with document variables.
[image]

**Step 2:**
Upload your document template to your server's storage path.

**Step 3:**
Create a new `TemplateProcessor` and assign values to the variables you placed in your document template.

```
$desc1 = User::find($id);   

$my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(storage_path('user_template.docx'));

$my_template->setValue('name', $desc1->name);
$my_template->setValue('email', $desc1->email);
$my_template->setValue('phone', $desc1->phone);
$my_template->setValue('address', $desc1->address);
```

**Step 4:**
Generate a safe file name(`user_1.docx` i.e.)

**Step 5:**
Create a `.docx` file from your template with the safe file name you generated in the previous step.

```
try{
    $my_template->saveAs(storage_path('user_1.docx'));
}catch (Exception $e){
    //handle exception
}
```

**Step 6:**
The complete code snippet to download the saved file.

```
public function exportUserToDoc(Request $request, $id)
{
    $desc1 = User::find($id);

    $my_template = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor(storage_path('user_template.docx'));

    $my_template->setValue('name', $desc1->name);
    $my_template->setValue('email', $desc1->email);
    $my_template->setValue('phone', $desc1->phone);
    $my_template->setValue('address', $desc1->address);      

    try{
        $my_template->saveAs(storage_path('user_1.docx'));
    }catch (Exception $e){
        //handle exception
    }

    return response()->download(storage_path('user_1.docx'));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public function wordExport($id){
    $doc = Doc::find($id);

    $templateProcessor = new \PhpOffice\PhpWord\TemplateProcessor('word-template/document.docx');

    $title = $doc->title;
    $reg = $doc->reg;

    $templateProcessor->setValue('title', $title);
    $templateProcessor->setValue('reg', $reg);

    $fileName = $title;
    $templateProcessor->saveAs($fileName . '.docx');
    return response()->download($fileName . '.docx')->deleteFileAfterSend(true);
}
```

Comment: Hi, heres my code, it works well. But now I m stuck myself - how to save it as pdf?